# Call to PUT or POST methods with angularjs stops working if parameter name is changed

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 methods in my controller class (ItensController.cs):

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Item value)
{
}
```

and

```
[ActionName("UpdateItemFees")]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateItemFees(int id, [FromBody]Item value)
{         
}
```

My client call is:

```
$http.put('/api/Itens/Put/' + $scope.osID, item)
$http.post('/api/Itens/UpdateItemFees/' + $scope.osID, item)
```

This works fine. But, if I change the name of the parameters in my controller class, it stops working:

```
public void Put(int osID, [FromBody]Item value)
{
}
```

and

```
[ActionName("UpdateItemFees")]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateItemFees(int osID, [FromBody]Item value)
{         
}
```

The errors are:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

```
'http://local/api/Itens/Put/3443'.
```

and

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

```
'http://local/api/Itens/UpdateItemFees/3443'.
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

What's wrong with this parameter's name change?

Other methods like Get, works normally.

Regards.

Comment: So are you showing us Java code for the controller? I've never seen '*' used in a variable name. I don't know that that is valid.It's possible there are URL mappings such as "....Itens/Put/id" that are setup to indicate the param will be called ID. Depends on the framework.

Comment: Are you sure that's `Itens` and not `Items` in your  client call ?

Comment: @Scott, the * is because I tryed to change the text style (bold), but did not work... I will edit the post. My controller class is c#.

Comment: @Aperçu, yes, is "Itens" and not "Items". Is portuguese :)! My controller class is "ItensController.cs". Thanks.

Comment: @Murphy okay, it's a little confusing with all the `Item` references in your controller part :)

Comment: Are you changing your route template after changing the variable name?

Comment: Hum... I don't know if I understand correctly, but, if you are talking about the global.asax aplication_start method, no, I didn't change. (post updated)

Answer (score 0):

try adding a route attribute:

```
[Route("api/Itens/{osID}")]
```

Asp.net MVC has built-in routes with default parameter names and `id` is one of those parameter names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146168/can-you-use-the-attribute-based-routing-of-webapi-2-with-webforms

Comment: route attributes work just fine. You may also want to edit your question, it's tagged "web api"

Comment: OK Chris, I will check the link. Regards.